# Trusted Web Activity - Google Chrome not shows the "access to camera and microphone" prompt after version 122

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, camera, microphone, trusted-web-activity

Trusted Web Activity after Google Chrome version 122 no longer shows the "access to camera and microphone" prompt. However, the same web application opened directly in Chrome still works well and the prompt appears.