# Call to Javascript "alert()" causes un-dismissible URL bar to appear

Tags: progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

Normal usage of the my PWA does not show the URL bar, however once making a call to Javascript's `alert()` function, the URL bar displays and cannot be interacted with. Only leaving the app and coming back to it hides the URL bar again.

Is there a security reason behind this quirk? Is it a bug in PWAs?

Here is a video demonstration: https://imgur.com/a/bE4jUro

Answer (score 0):

reloading the page removes the url bar.
js open('current_url')

Yeah, the new android Chrome updates brought a bunch of bugs, like this one
[Trusted Web Activity - Google Chrome not shows the "access to camera and microphone" prompt after version 122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78113905/trusted-web-activity-google-chrome-not-shows-the-access-to-camera-and-microph)